# AngularJs - resort array via a field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array like this :

```
[Object,Object,Object];
```

Each Object has property which name is "rate". All I want is sorting this object with rate property.

I have variable (`$scope.restaurants.data`) in my JS. and this is structure of this variable:

```
Array[3]
0:Object
  ID:3
  name:"bestRest"
  profile:"rest.png"
  rate:1
  restaurantCitySlug:"NY"
  slug:"foo"
  __proto__:Object
1:Object
  ID:7
  name:"bestRes3t"
  profile:"rest7.png"
  rate:0
  restaurantCitySlug:"NY"
  slug:"fo4o"
  __proto__:Object
2:Object
  ID:7
  name:"bestR242es3t"
  profile:"re3st7.png"
  rate:2
  restaurantCitySlug:"NY"
  slug:"fo244o"
  __proto__:Object
```

And my exeption is :

```
Array[3]
0:Object
  ID:7
  name:"bestRes3t"
  profile:"rest7.png"
  rate:0
  restaurantCitySlug:"NY"
  slug:"fo4o"
  __proto__:Object
1:Object
  ID:3
  name:"bestRest"
  profile:"rest.png"
  rate:1
  restaurantCitySlug:"NY"
  slug:"foo"
  __proto__:Object
2:Object
  ID:7
  name:"bestR242es3t"
  profile:"re3st7.png"
  rate:2
  restaurantCitySlug:"NY"
  slug:"fo244o"
  __proto__:Object
```

Comment: You can use `orderBy` filter for this.like this `$filter('orderBy')(YOURDATA, 'rate')`

Comment: @Hadi  I want do this in my controller not in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`$filter`** **`orderBy`** in controller as below

```
  $scope.restaurants.data = $filter('orderBy')($scope.restaurants.data, 'rate');
```

Comment: `$.restaurants.data`, typo ?

Answer (score 1):

Try use this

```
sortData = $filter('orderBy')(YOURDATA, 'rate');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use plain old [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
$scope.restaurants.data.sort((a, b) => a.rate - b.rate)
```